# about conjecture "every finite nonabelian p-group admits a noninner automorphism of order p"

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, conjectures, p-groups

by "The Kourovka Notebook. Unsolved Problems in Group Theory" there is a strong conjecture asserts that every finite nonabelian p-group admits a noninner automorphism of order p.
What about finite abelian p-group? 
Is there a finite abelian p-group without noninner automorphism of order p?
If yes can we for example by changing "order p" in conjecture make it for all finite p-group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For abelian $p$-groups this problem is not that hard.

If it has a cyclic group of order $p^2$ as a factor, then this contributes the needed automorphism.

If not then it is elementary abelian, and the order of the automorphism group (which is $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$) is again divisible by $p$ as long as it is not cyclic of prime order.

Clearly if the group is cyclic of prime order then it has no automorphism of order $p$.